# Centering the caption of figure without warning

Tags: captions, warnings

Original,

[image]

After I add a package `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}`, it became 
[image]

it's exactly I wanted, however, an unexpected warning came out, it said:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty:
>   Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
>   (caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
>   See the caption package documentation for explanation.

My question is: how can I solve this problem without warning?

**Update** all the packages and `documentclass` used here are:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,standalone}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{tikz,forest}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

Comment: You've not told us what document class you are using: `caption` gives a warning for any it does not 'know'.

Comment: my class is `\documentclass[12pt,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
`

Comment: If you are using a class for journal or conference submission, _do not mess with the layout_!

Comment: Did you mean I need not care the `warnings`?

Comment: Using the `conference` class option gives you centered captions, without the need for the `caption` package (`\documentclass[12pt,draftcls,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}`).

Comment: When you are submitting something to conferences or an article to journals, then you are the content provider. Not the layouter. If you start messing with the layout put forth by a given template, the journal or conference editors have to spend extra time reediting your contribution because it does not fit into the guidelines set by the journal or conference.

Comment: @karlkoeller it works, only difference is the smaller font, how to not change the font size.

Comment: @WangyanLi This is the default font, either with `conference` or without it.

Comment: @karlkoeller thx, I will go the traditional way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to summarize some comments above:

`\documentclass[12pt,draftcls,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}` will give what you expect. In general, you should not tweak around with the layout of some journal as you are just supposed to give the content, not the design. Some templates may be ugly, but the journal will stick to it and therefore change your settings back (or worse, reject your article in the current form).

Off-topic: `color` is almost outdated and `xcolor` should be used. The latter is already loaded by `tikz`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `conference` option also removes page numbers from the document.